# What are the folders "Desktop" and "[My full name]" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, user-profiles

I have been investigating the folders "Desktop" and "[My full name]".

When I type "Desktop" into Windows Explorer, I get a folder that is not `C:\Users\\[username]\Desktop`, and only "Desktop" shows up in the top bar. It contains all files and folder in my desktop folder, as well as [My Full Name] folder, This PC, Libraries, Network, Control Panel, and Recycle Bin. Typing `Desktop\\..` brings up This PC. If I open Powershell here, it just goes to `C:\Users\\[username]\Desktop`. If I open  [My Full Name], it also only shows that in the top bar and acts like `C:\Users\\[username]`. Any folder I open from there shows [My Full Name] > [folder name] in the top bar, but shows the true path if you click on it. If I pin `C:\Users\\[username]` to Quick Access and click on it, it brings me to [My Full Name].

What are these one-name/no-path folders, and why are they're properties so weird?

Comment: Desktop, a virtual folder, is the root folders of all other folders. It is comprised of namespace items (like Computer) defined in the registry and real files from your user profile's Desktop folder and the all users' Desktop folder. A lot of what was once on it is now hidden as it confused users (eg along with My Computer was the Internet as a folder with all open pages)

Comment: You can access it by typing `shell:desktop` in the explorer bar.